# Java URL constructor ignores path segment

Tags: java, url, path, segment

I am using the Java URL constructor "URL(URL context, String spec)" found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URL.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.net.URL,java.lang.String)) but the constructed URL is not what I expect - it is leaving out a path segment provided in the context parameter.

As an example, this code

```
new URL(new URL("http://asdf.com/z"), "a/b/c");
```

produces a URL with value

> http://asdf.com/a/b/c

So it has left out of "z" path segment.

I have two questions:

1. What is the meaning of "context" the first parameter here in the java doc? I could not find mention of it in the URL specification nor did I really find it in java doc.
2. Is leaving out the "z" expected behavior?

Thanks!

Comment: If `http://asdf.com/z` when a web page in a browser, then a link to `a/b/c` would go to `http://asdf.com/a/b/c`. I'm not going to figure out the very abstract text of rfc2396.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the meaning of "context" the first parameter here in the java doc?

It's like the "base URL" of the `spec` parameter. If `context` is `https://example.com`, and `spec` is `/foo`, the constructor would create `https://example.com/foo`. It's similar to (but not exactly the same as, as we'll see later) asking "I am currently on `https://example.com`, and I want to go to `/foo`, what would my final URL be?"

> Is leaving out the "z" expected behavior?

Yes. If you follow through the [rules of resolving a relative URL against an base URL](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396#section-5.2) in RFC 2396 with regards to this case, you will reach this step:

> (6) If this step is reached, then we are resolving a relative-path
> reference.  The relative path needs to be merged with the base
> URI's path.  Although there are many ways to do this, we will
> describe a simple method using a separate string buffer.
>
> (a) All but the last segment of the base URI's path component is
> copied to the buffer.  In other words, any characters after the
> last (right-most) slash character, if any, are excluded.
>
> (b) The reference's path component is appended to the buffer
> string.

The "last segment" here, refers to `z`, and that is *not* added to the buffer. Right after that, the path `a/b/c` "is appended to the buffer". Steps (c) onwards deals with removing `.` and `..`, which is irrelevant here.

Note that RFC 2386 doesn't say you MUST implement the algorithm in this way, but that whatever your implementation is, your output must match the output of that algorithm:

> The above algorithm is intended to provide an example by which the
> output of implementations can be tested -- implementation of the
> algorithm itself is not required.

So yeah, this is expected. To keep the `/z`, you should add another `/` after the `z`:

```
new URL(new URL("http://asdf.com/z/"), "a/b/c")
```

This way the "last segment" becomes the empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You can treat the context like the current directory in file system.
With context "http://asdf.com/z", the current directory is "http://asdf.com/", and use "a/b/c" as the spec will result a full path "http://asdf.com/a/b/c".